# Microsoft Cognitive Services face id

Tags: face-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/cognitive-services/Face/quickstarts/php

i did this php example and published at microsoft azure web server.

->Identify Faces in Images
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/cognitive-services/Face/QuickStarts/PHP#Identify

Microsoft Cognitive Services face id not returning.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: link code :https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/cognitive-services/Face/QuickStarts/PHP#Identify

Comment: Did you replace the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key and added request parameters? As @MariaInesParnisari suggested, sharing full code (by hiding your access key) will help quickly debug.

Comment: yes, but just to make shure , where is the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key in dashboard?

Comment: @claudiovangar here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIEof.png

Comment: not working at http://18k.azurewebsites.net/test.php

Comment: hi

1-face recognition  works good  at http://api.dnplugins.com/somejob/test.php

Comment: 2-but not working at my azurewebsites  http://18k.azurewebsites.net/test.php

Comment: 3-test in input box with image link : https://www.havenondemand.com/sample-content/images/family.jpg

Comment: 4-test.php please dowload from my dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/yxgfsofiprfd7s6/test.php?dl=0

Comment: 5-i installed composer and http requst2.php  but i think maybe the problem is here

Comment: hello how to install pear in microsoftazure console?